# Construction of Markov processes with density

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I have a question about this paper [BH](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aop/1176990437), which is one of the basic literature on reflecting Brownian motions.

For any bounded open subset $D$, the semigroup $\{T_t\}_{t>0}$ on $L^{2}(D,dx)$ generated by Neumann laplacian admits an integral kernel.
 If $D$ is bounded Lipschitz domain, $\{T_t\}_{t>0}$ has the integral kernel $p_{t}(x,y)$ which is continuous on $(0,\infty) \times \bar{D} \times \bar{D}$.

The authors of this paper constructed reflecting Brownian motion on $\bar{D}$ in the following procedure:

1. They proved $H^{1}(D)$ (1st order Sobolev space with Neumann boundary condition) is a regular Dirichlet form on $L^{2}(\bar{D},dx)$. Since, $H^{1}(D)$ is regular on $L^{2}(\bar{D},dx)$, there exists a Hunt process $X=(X_t,P_x)$ on $\bar{D}$ associated with $H^{1}(D)$.
2. However, $X=(X_t,P_x)$ does not necessarily have transition density. So they introduced new probability measures $\{Q_x\}_{x \in \bar{D}}$. Each $Q_{x}$ is defined by
   \begin{equation*}
   Q_{x}(A \circ \theta_{t})=\int_{D}p_{t}(x,y)P_{y}(A)\,dy,\quad x\in\bar{D},\ t>0,\ A \in\mathcal{F}.
   \end{equation*}
   Here, $\theta_t$ is the shift operator of $X=(X_t,P_x)$ and $\mathcal{F}$ is the filtration generated by $X$.

**My question**

They claimed $Q_{x}$ uniquely determines a probability measure $Q_x$ on $\mathcal{F}$. However, I don't know why... For example, how do they define $Q_{x}(\{X_0=x\})$ ?

Comment: I did not look into the linked paper, but this seems to be a standard trick to get rid of the "properly exceptional set". Think of a 2-D BM which is stopped at the origin. With probability 1 it never hits the origin, so the semigroup of this process is the same as that of the usual BM, except that $T_t f(0) = f(0)$ for the former one, so technically it does not have transition densities. Under $Q_x$, however, the stopped Brownian motion becomes the usual one.

Comment: (continued) In any case, the expression for $Q_x$ that you gave, together with the obvious condition $Q_x(\{X_0 = x\}) = 1$, defines the measure on all cylinder sets, so indeed it does determine the probability measure uniquely (as long as it defines it at all, but this is a different question; for Hunt processes it does).

Comment: In other words, are you saying that $(X_t ,Q_x)$ will become Hunt process  under condition $Q_{x}(\{X_0=x\})=1$?

Comment: Yes, I think so. (The condition $Q_x(\{X_0=x\})$ should actually follow automatically if all paths are càdlàg, because $Q_x(\{|X_t-x|<r\})=\int_{B(x,r)}p_t(x,y)dy\to 1$ as $t\to 0$, so $Q_x(\{X_{0+}=x\})=1$).

Comment: Sorry. To show $\lim_{t \to 0}Q_{x}(\{|X_t-x|<r\})=1$, did you use the following condition: for each $\omega \in \Omega$, $t \mapsto X_{t}(\omega)$ is right continuous on $[0,\infty)$ ? Here, $\Omega$ is the measurable space on which $(X_t,P_x)$ is defined.

Comment: No, I only used the definition of $Q_x$ and the properties of $p_t(x,y)$: $Q_x(\{|X_t - x|<r\})=\int_D p_t(x,y)P_y(\{|X_0 - x|<r\})dy=\int_{B(x,r)}p_t(x,y)dy$.

Comment: If so, how do you compute $\lim_{t \to 0}\int_{B(x,r)}p_{t}(x,y)dy=1$?

Comment: This is where you need some information about $p_t$. In Bass–Hsu they prove an upper bound (Thm 2.3), which is more then sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, I see. For a general Hunt process $X=(X_t,P_x)$ on a metric measure space $(E,d,\mu)$, even if we obtain a (unique) continuous transition density  $p_{t}(x,y)$, there is a possibility that $\int_{B(x,r)}p_{t}(x,y)\mu(dy)$ can not be calculated explicitly. In this case, there is a possibility that $Q_{x}(X_{0+}=x)=1$ can not be proved, where $Q_x(A \circ \theta_t)=\int_{E}p_{t}(x,y)P_{y}(A)\,\mu(dy)$. However, $(X_t,Q_x)$ becomes Hunt process if we assume $Q_{x}(X_0=x)=1$?

Comment: Definitely continuity of $p_t(x,y)$ is not sufficient. Consider 1-D BM $Z_t$ in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ killed with rate $1/|x|$, and define $X_t=Z_t$ if the starting point is $x\ne 0$ and $X_t=0$ when the starting point is $0$. Then both $Z_t$ and $X_t$ are Hunt processes with the same Dirichlet form, and (continuous version of) the transition density of $Z_t$ extends continuously to the real line in such a way that $p_t(0,y)=p_t(x,0)=0$. This would mean that under $Q_0$, the process $X_t$ dies out immediately, and so it is not a Hunt process. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Okay, I got it. Thank you for telling me carefully.